# Tool to generate keyboard layout diagram

Tags: windows, diagram, keyboard-layout

Is there any tool that produces a diagram of the current keyboard layout, and shows secondary characters typed when pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> (or is editable so I can manually add those)?

An example from Wikipedia:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the windows built in tools "On Screen Keyboard" and the "Snipping Tool" to get an image of the current keyboard layout:
[image]
Then the one with the AltGr button pressed:
[image]

And use just about any image editing program, personally I used [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/), to recolor and merge one on the other with a little offset for clarity:
[image]